# Not Firing attachEvent in Javascript in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dynamics-crm-2011

I have following piece of Javascript where I used `attachEvent`.

```
crmForm.all.new_height.attachEvent ("onkeyup", doCalc);
function doCalc ()
{
   alert("hello");
}
```

where new_height is one field. So my aim is to fire event during `onkeyup` of `new_height` field. So I used this Javascript in Form `OnLoad` Event, but it didn't fire when I write into the text of `new_height` field.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, use:

```
crmForm.all.new_height.attachEvent("onkeyup", function(){doCalc();});
```

Side note for anyone else looking at this post.  Don't forget crmForm.all is IE specific & attachEvent only works in IE (and Opera).

Inside CRM 2011, you'd be better off to use:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('telephone2')._control._element.attachEvent("onkeyup", function(){alert('test');});
```

It too is IE specific (uses attachEvent) but it uses the Xrm variable.

Comment: :Have you checked?..i think its not working i have checked but it didnt work for me...

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me fine.  Make sure that doCalc is defined.  Secondly, if that still doesn't work swap in `alert("test");` in for `doCalc();` to see that it works.  If alert doesn't work, then try another field.

Comment: :have you checked in MS CRM 2011?because thats working in CRM 4.0 but it doesnt working for me in CRM 2011

Comment: @KartikPatel Yeah, it works fine for me within CRM 2011.  (Granted, I'm testing using the IE Developer tools).  I added to the answer an Xrm method.  Swap in the "telephone2" field for whatever you'd like and see if that works for you.

Comment: @KartikPatel try executing this inside Developer Tools.  Prepend "frames[0]." to the above code.  http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2012/02/xrm-2011-javascript-another-101-lesson.html